# C++ IDE detecting syntax errors without recompilation?

Tags: c++, ide, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I work on Code::Blocks IDE on Windows. Great amount of time is wasted for code recompilation to find errors.
Is there a C++ IDE that detects syntax errors without recompilation?

I suppose any clang-based IDE would be an option?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Visual Studio with it's IntelliSense.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be surprised at how efficient Qt Creator is at detecting C++ errors before compilation. Give it a try!

Eclipse has that awesome feature for Java, but IIRC the CDT framework is not as powerful: it detects only vague syntax errors.

Comment: Downloaded Qt Creator yesterday. :) I am impressed, it's great.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's VisualStudio which is available for free with the Express edition is very good if you are on Windows. Apple's XCode is pretty good, but it gives up after only one error, it's error messages are very short and cryptic, and I believe it is only available on Mac OS X. Unfortunately I do not know of an IDE with this support for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Configure code blocks to work with clang. Working fine for me.